# allow click event on an overlay on entire tableview

Tags: objective-c, overlay, uitableview

I have tableview for which i have set an overlay for entire table programmatically. All that is working fine. But now i want user to be able to click on the cell of the tabeview. I know its not possible as overlay is on foreground. But i want to know if there is any other way to do it.
any idea would be helpful.

This is the code for overlay

UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,_tblRestaurantList.frame.size.width,500000)];

[overlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.6]];
 [_tblRestaurantList addSubview:overlay];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set `overlay.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`